# How to add a icon to Android JWPlayer

Tags: android, jwplayer

I have succesfully added JWPlayer to my activity, and now i would like to add a button to the player that executes a function.
I followed this guid on [github](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-android-demo)
I also followed this [guide](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skins/), but again, no luck.

activity_jwplayerfragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_jwplayerreview.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_jwplayerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.JWPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/jwplayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/output"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there're no way to add anything when full screen